# Get awk error "redirection has null string value" while splitting file

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, logs

In suse  linux for slow query log to split on an hourly basis, I am using the script below.
How to resolve the error?

```
#!/bin/bash    
# split mysql slow query log by hour    
usage() {    
cat <<EOF
Usage: $0 [options]    
[REQUIRED]
-l
EOF
exit 1    
}    
while getopts "l:" opt; do
case $opt in
l) slowlog="$OPTARG" ;;
esac
done    
[ -z "$slowlog" ] && usage   
awk '{
if ($0~/^# Time*/) {
split($4, h, ":");
hour=h[1];
minute=h[2];
splitfile="mysql-slow.log-split-"substr($0, 9, 6)"-"hour".txt";
print $0 >> splitfile
} else {
print $0 >> splitfile
}
}' "$slowlog"
```

But during execution getting below error:

```
mysql@eudc-mysql-lx03:/mysql-work/chandra> sh -x test_slow.sh -l eudc-mysql-lx03-slow.log
+ getopts l: opt
+ case $opt in
+ slowlog=eudc-mysql-lx03-slow.log
+ getopts l: opt
+ '[' -z eudc-mysql-lx03-slow.log ']'
+ awk '{
if ($0~/^# Time*/) {
split($4, h, ":");
hour=h[1];
minute=h[2];
splitfile="mysql-slow.log-split-"substr($0, 9, 6)"-"hour".txt";
print $0 >> splitfile
} else {
print $0 >> splitfile
}
}' eudc-mysql-lx03-slow.log
awk: cmd. line:8: (FILENAME=eudc-mysql-lx03-slow.log FNR=1) fatal: expression for `>>' redirection has null string value
```

Comment: Consider formatting your question using code blocks to make it more readable.

Comment: Since `splitfile` only gets assigned in the `if` block, it will be unassigned in the `else` block for lines of the log preceding any `# Time` marker.

Comment: #steel: Can u pls let me know what changes need to do to make it executable correctly.

Comment: Remove else statement from code and it is executing but now only time stamp is coming in log file.other statements are not logging.
#!/bin/bash

# split mysql slow query log by hour
# robert@krzykawski.com
usage() {

cat <<EOF
Usage: $0 [options]

[REQUIRED]
-l
EOF

exit 1

}

while getopts "l:" opt; do
case $opt in
l) slowlog="$OPTARG" ;;
esac
done

[ -z "$slowlog" ] && usage

awk '{
if ($0~/^# Time*/) {
split($4, h, ":");
hour=h[1];
minute=h[2];
splitfile="mysql-slow.log-split-"substr($0, 9, 6)"-"hour".txt";
print $0 >> splitfile
}
}' "$slowlog"

Comment: cat mysql-slow.log-split-161214-9.txt
# Time: 161214  9:13:20
# Time: 161214  9:43:08

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [edit] your question to add extra information. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Also, comments can be deleted with no warning.

Comment: Since the problem is because the `splitfile` variable isn't set for the first line of your input file, we also need to see the exact input file you are using to be ab;e to help you. So add that to your question as well, and use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are branching to the `else` statement before going through the  `if` statement, thus you are using variable `splitline` before assignment, like stated in the comments. The way I see it, the only reason you are using awk here is to extract the date and redirect to a different file each time the hour or date is incremented. You code would work only if you are guaranteed that the first line of your log is always a timestamp, but it appears it is not the case. You need to start logging at the first timestamp you encounter, for this I propose to you this simple tweak to your `awk` snippet:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ date_found=0 }
     /^# Time/       { date_found=1 }
     date_found == 0 { continue }
     date_found == 1 {
       split($4, h, ":");
       hour=h[1];
       date=$3
       splitfile="mysql-slow.log-split-"date"-"hour".txt";
       date_found=2
     }
     {print $0 >> splitfile}' "$slowlog"
```

Downside to this method: you will not store log content prior to the first timestamp of the big log file ! If you want to store the lines prior to the first timestamp in the first split file, you have to extract the date before running your main awk invocation. It gets a tad more complicated but you could do this:

```
first_date=$(awk '/^# Time/{print $3" "$4; exit}' "$slowlog")
awk -v init_date="$first_date" '
     BEGIN{ 
       split(init_date, a, " ")
       date=a[1]
       split(a[2], b, ":")
       hour=b[1] 
     }
     /^# Time/ {
       split($4, h, ":");
       hour=h[1];
       date=$3
     }
     {
       splitfile="mysql-slow.log-split-"date"-"hour".txt";
       print $0 >> splitfile
     }' "$slowlog"
```

Either solutions should suit the needs you expressed in the question. Don't hesitate to ask questions on the code if you need to.

Comment: there is not input file in `first_date=$(awk'...')`, may be add `"$slow_log"`

Comment: @Archemar indeed I seem to have forgotten it thank you for your insight !